# How to find topics and phrases (verbs/adjectives) that are grouped with a specific word?

Tags: r, text, nlp

I have a large tidy data set with columns containing text responses(i.e., in a grant application) and rows as the individual organization applying for the grant. I'm trying to find the topics and phrases grouped with a specific word (e.g., "funder"/"funding"). More specifically, what adjectives and verbs are being grouped with these tokens?

So for example

```
text <- "This funding would help us create a new website and hire talented people."
```

So "funding" can be grouped with verbs like "create", "hire", and adjective phrases like "new website", "talented people".

I'm doing this in R. Does anyone have a package or program in which they'd recommend doing this? I've found cleanNLP, but not sure if this is the most convenient package. Would I need to tokenize all the words? If so, wouldn't I have problems grouping phrases?

I'm fairly new to NLP/text mining, so I apologize for the introductory question.

Thank you!

Comment: I am working with `corpus` and `udpipe`

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need general data analysis advice, you should ask someplace like [stats.se] or [datascience.se].

Answer (score 2):

This is a huge area to start exploring.

I would strongly recommend taking a look at the tidytextmining book and package, as well as the authors personal blogs (https://juliasilge.com, http://varianceexplained.org) there is a huge amount of great work there to get you started, and its really well written for people new to NLP.

Also really helpful for what you are looking for are the widyr and udpipe libraries.

Here's a couple of examples:
Using widyr we can look at the pairwise pmi between a word, say funding, and all other words that it has some relationship with. For info on PMI check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13492808/2862791

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
texts <- tibble(text = c('This funding would help us create a new website and hire talented people',
                         'this random funding function talented people',
                         'hire hire hire new website funding',
                         'fun fun fun for all'))


tidy_texts %>%
        pairwise_pmi(word, id) %>%
        filter(item1 == 'funding') %>% 
        top_n(5, wt = pmi) %>%
        arrange(desc(pmi))

 item1   item2        pmi
   <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 funding this     -0.0205
 2 funding would    -0.0205
 3 funding help     -0.0205
 4 funding us       -0.0205
```

So to introduce adjectives and phrases you could look at udpipe as boski suggested.
I'm going to reproduce the above to calculate the PMI too, as it's a really intuitive and quick to compute metric

```
library(udpipe)
english <- udpipe_download_model(language = "english")
ud_english <- udpipe_load_model(english$file_model)

tagged <- udpipe_annotate(ud_english, x = texts$text)
tagged_df <- as.data.frame(tagged)


tagged_df %>%
        filter(upos == 'ADJ' | 
                       token == 'funding') %>%
        pairwise_pmi(token, doc_id) %>%
        filter(item1 == 'funding')


  item1   item2      pmi
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1 funding new      0.170
2 funding talented 0.170
```

You've mentioned cleanNLP, which is a great library for this kind of work. It makes it easy to access udpipe and spacyr and a few other methods which do the kind of tokenisation and tagging needed for that adjective finding.

If you can get past the setup details spacyr is my preferred option just because its the fastest, but if speed isn't an issue I would just go with udpipe as its very easy to use.

Would I need to tokenize all the words? If so, wouldn't I have problems grouping phrases?

So udpipe, and other text annotators, have a solution for this. 
In udpipe you can use 'keywords_collocation()' which identifies words which occur together more frequently than expected through random chance.

We would need to have a text dataset bigger than the three junk sentences I've written above to get a reproducible example.

But you can find out alot through this blog:
https://bnosac.github.io/udpipe/docs/doc7.html

Sorry this reply is kind of a collection of links ... but as I said it's a huge area of study.

Comment: Wow, thanks! And I agree, it's quite a large area so I'm grateful for the links and examples you gave. I've used tidytext to tokenize words and do simple analyses, including sentiment analysis, word co-occurrence, etc. Unfortunately, I didn't know where to start to even begin exploring this topic. So thanks again for the direction. I also have spaCy installed, which I'll try to use along with udpipe.

Comment: The above was fairly straightforward. But with the udpipe package, something seems to be off. I install and load the package. Create the `English` variable. But when I run the `ud_english <- udpipe_load_model(x$file_model)` I get  `Error in x$file_model : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: The above has a mistake, sorry.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I saw the same in the documentation, but your example now works.